# When should I disconnect from Google Play Services in my Android app?

Tags: android, google-play-services, location-client

My app uses the Location Client in order to retrieve current location and also route to points placed by user on a map. I am new to the google play services and am wondering as far as best practices go when should I disconnect my LocationClient if ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android training site suggests two approaches to connect and disconnect the `LocationClient`. In the [Retrieving the Current Location](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) training, the `LocationClient` is initialized in `onCreate`, `connect()` is called in `onStart` and `disconnect()` is called in `onStop` like this (taken from the [source code](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/LocationUpdates.zip)).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();
}
```

Then you can choose when and where to start or stop the location updates.

In [Recognizing the User's Current Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) the `LocationClient` is initialized each time the user wants to request or stop activity recognition updates. First, `connect()` is called, then in `onConnected`, `requestActivityUpdates` or `removeActivityUpdates` is called and immediatly after that `disconnect()` is called. In the sample [source code](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityRecognition.zip) there is a class called `DetectionRequester` that starts the activity recognition updates:

```
public void requestUpdates() {
    getActivityRecognitionClient().connect();
}

@Override
private void onConnected() {
    getActivityRecognitionClient().requestActivityUpdates(...);
    getActivityRecognitionClient().disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    mActivityRecognitionClient = null;
}

private ActivityRecognitionClient getActivityRecognitionClient() {
    if (mActivityRecognitionClient == null) {
        mActivityRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(...);
    }
    return mActivityRecognitionClient;
}
```

And there is another similar class called `DetectionRemover` that stops the activity recognition updates.

Another approach is to have both methods (`requestUpdates` and `removeUpdates`) in the same class, like this:

```
public enum RequestType {
    START, STOP;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    switch (mRequestType) {
        case START:
            getActivityRecognitionClient().requestActivityUpdates(...);
            break;
        case STOP:
            getActivityRecognitionClient().removeActivityUpdates(...);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    getActivityRecognitionClient().disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    mActivityRecognitionClient = null;
}


public void requestUpdates() {
    mRequestType = RequestType.START;
    getActivityRecognitionClient().connect();
}

public void removeUpdates() {
    mRequestType = RequestType.STOP;
    getActivityRecognitionClient().connect();
}

private ActivityRecognitionClient getActivityRecognitionClient() {
    if (mActivityRecognitionClient == null) {
        mActivityRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(...);
    }
    return mActivityRecognitionClient;
}
```

The same approach can be used to start and stop location updates.

I don't know wich of this approaches might be considered best practice, but they are in the sample source code. I personally use the third approach in all my projects. The third approach was in the Activity Recognition sample until recently.

Comment: LocationClient is now deprecated.